# Point a cell where cell name is made of content of 2 different cells

Tags: excel, vba

In cell A2 i have value F and in B2 I have content "4", then macros to point F4 cell value.
I have written following code but it is giving object error.
Please help

```
Sub TransferValues()

Dim rngA As Range
Dim rngB As Range
Dim srcAddress As Range
Dim destAddress As Range
Dim r As Long   'row iterator
VarW1 = "a.xlsx"
Sht1 = "Sheet1"
Set rngA = Range("H2", Range("H2").End(xlDown))
Set rngB = rngA.Offset(0, 1)

For r = 1 To rngA.Rows.Count
Set srcAddress = Range(rngA(r).Value & Range("H2").Value).Value
Set destAddress = Range(rngB(r).Value & Range("I2").Value).Value
destAddress.Value = srcAddress.Value
Next

End Sub)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not familiar with `EVALUATE` and `INDIRECT` for VBA - you may use this:

```
x = Range(Range("A2").Value & Range("B2").Value).Value
```

Also you may use `Cells(row, column)` syntax to loop between cells.

Comment: please check following problem :   "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871178/macro-to-map-1-row-multiple-colum-sets-to-another-same-set"

Comment: I am getting object error in following------------------------------------------  Set srcAddress = Range(rngA(r).Value & Range("H2").Value).Value

Comment: @user2069033 please share at least relevant part of the code  by editing the question

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula: `=INDIRECT(A2&B2)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Indirect formula.  For your example, =indirect(A2&B2) will give you the value in F4.

[Here's a nice write-up](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm) of what you can do with indirect.

Comment: Hi... if i have A2:A96 and B2:B96 then how it is possible to mix bot cells and to point corresponding cells.     when I used indirect in my code an error "Sub or Function not defined" displayed.

Comment: @user2069033 use `Evaluate` VBA function to calculate Excel sheet formula.